# Difference between .call and .apply

Tags: javascript, native

Is there a simple way to passing all arguments from one function to another and sending `this` also.

I have tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/v92Xr/

```
var f1 = function() {
    f2.call(this, arguments);
};
var f2 = function() {
    console.log(arguments);
};
f1("abc", "def", "hij");
```

but it leaves me all the arguments from f1 is stacked in f2 arguments 0:

```
f2->arguments[0] == f1->arguments
```

Ok and when i run the `apply` method instead it works: http://jsfiddle.net/v92Xr/1/

```
var f1 = function() {
    f2.apply(this, arguments);
};
var f2 = function() {
    console.log(arguments);
};
f1("abc", "def", "hij");
```

So can anyone please tell me what's the difference between `call` and `apply` is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you've just discovered the difference yourself.

`call` is almost identical to way you would normally call a function except there is an extra parameter at the start of the parameter list where you place the reference for the `this` object.

`apply` also has the first parameter as the `this` object but the second parameter is expected to be an array.  This array is used to supply all the arguments that the called function is expecting.  Element 0 maps to the first argument in the functions argument list, element 1 to the second and so on.

Answer (score 1):

**call** MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

> Calls a function with a given this value and **arguments provided individually**.

```
fun.call(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])
```

**apply** MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

> Calls a function with a given this value and **arguments provided as an array**.

```
fun.apply(thisArg[, argsArray])
```